# Getting error Route without Measure from Make Route Event tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing

I'm using make a route event tool, i want to generate lines that have specific measurements.

I made sure that the properties of the polylines were Polyline M as opposed to polyline, as well as my table has a foreign field, which links to the shapefile.

When I use make a route event, the output layer does not show on the workspace.

I open the attribute table of the output that make a route event produces, and it says, "route without measure".

I don't understand what this message means. I made sure that the tabular properties are the same of both the shapefile and the table that contains the measurement of the start to end points. I don't know what else to do to make the output layer display.

Can the "route without measure error" message be attributed to the unique identifier fields in both table or a projection issue?

Comment: Are routes calibrated? Is your 'foreign' field TEXT type, which is the only reliable.

Comment: @FelixIP What do you mean by routes being "calibrated". The foriegn fields are numerical not text.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your route layer is not calibrated (as hinted by @FelixIP). It's not enough to create a polylineM featureclass you also need to give those polylines a measure along their length. The measure does not have to be in the units of the dataset (although it usually is). So for example you may have a dataset in UTM (so in metres) but your measure is in Miles.  There is a walk through exercise [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000049000000) that will help you.

Comment: I've calibrated the route layer. I still have the error message " route without measure".